# preparing R datasets for publication - removing repeated items

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I stored the results of data analysis in a dataframe (or tibble) and I would like to prepare it for publication (send to latex) by removing repeated items from the dataframe. Is there any R function that does this job automatically? The current example is `my_cars` and I want to turn it into `my_cars_publication`.

```
library(dplyr)

my_cars <- 
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(car_name=rownames(.))   %>% 
  select(car_name, everything()) %>% 
  separate(car_name, c("car_name1", "car_name2"),sep=" " )

my_cars 

my_cars_publication <- my_cars
car_name1_index <- c(2,5, 9:14, 21 )
car_name2_index <- c(2)


my_cars_publication[car_name1_index,"car_name1"] <- NA
my_cars_publication[car_name2_index,"car_name2"] <- NA


my_cars_publication
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is replacing `duplicated` rows? `my_cars$car_name1[duplicated(my_cars$car_name1)] <- NA` or is there more that you need?

Comment: `my_cars[!duplicated(my_cars), ]` should do it. `duplicated` is very sueful

Comment: @thelatemail  I don't have duplicated rows. I want to remove duplicated cell values o be suitable for an academic paper. I edited my question.

Comment: Code golf, instead of `duplicated` solutions: `unique(my_cars)`. (The `unique.data.frame` method calls `!duplicated(...)`.)

Comment: Is `my_cars_publication` your expected output? You do not remove any rows in them. You are just assigning duplicated values to `NA`. So `my_cars %>%
  mutate_at(vars(car_name1, car_name2), ~replace(., duplicated(.), NA))` ? Or in base R `mycars[cols] <- lapply(my_cars[cols], function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done on each column using `dplyr::if_else`, base `ifelse`, or base `replace`.

```r
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(car_name=rownames(.))   %>% 
  select(car_name, everything()) %>% 
  separate(car_name, c("car_name1", "car_name2"),sep=" " ) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(car_name1, car_name2),
            ~ replace(., c(FALSE, .[-1] == head(., n = -1)), NA))
#           ~ if_else(c(FALSE, .[-1] == head(., n=-1)), .[NA], .))
#           ~ ifelse(c(FALSE, .[-1] == head(., n=-1)), .[NA], .))

# Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 3 rows [2, 4, 29].
# Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [6].
#    car_name1   car_name2  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1      Mazda         RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2       <NA>        <NA> 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3     Datsun         710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4     Hornet           4 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 5       <NA>  Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 6    Valiant        <NA> 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# 7     Duster         360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
# 8       Merc        240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# 9       <NA>         230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# 10      <NA>         280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
# 11      <NA>        280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
# 12      <NA>       450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
# 13      <NA>       450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
# 14      <NA>      450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
# 15  Cadillac   Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
# 16   Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
# 17  Chrysler    Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
# 18      Fiat         128 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# 19     Honda       Civic 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# 20    Toyota     Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
# 21      <NA>      Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# 22     Dodge  Challenger 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
# 23       AMC     Javelin 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
# 24    Camaro         Z28 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
# 25   Pontiac    Firebird 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
# 26      Fiat        X1-9 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
# 27   Porsche       914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# 28     Lotus      Europa 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
# 29      Ford     Pantera 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
# 30   Ferrari        Dino 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
# 31  Maserati        Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
# 32     Volvo        142E 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

(The reason I chose `.[NA]` in some of the options is because `if_else` *enforces* both the "true" and "false" vectors to have the same class; `NA` by itself is technically `logical`, which matches neither `character` or `numeric`. I could have hard-coded `NA_character_`, but I thought a more general approach that matches the correct variant based on the original column. Did you know there are at least six variants of `NA`? Try `lapply(list(T, 1L, 1, "1", Sys.time(), Sys.Date()), function(z) class(z[NA]))` to show six, and compare them to determine they are not `identical`.)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate_at` on selected columns and `replace` them with `NA` if they are `duplicated`.

```
library(dplyr)
cols <- c("car_name1", "car_name2")

my_cars %>% mutate_at(vars(cols), ~replace(., duplicated(.), NA))

#   car_name1   car_name2  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#1      Mazda         RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4
#2       <NA>        <NA> 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4
#3     Datsun         710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.32 18.6  1  1    4    1
#4     Hornet           4 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.21 19.4  1  0    3    1
#5       <NA>  Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.44 17.0  0  0    3    2
#6    Valiant        <NA> 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.46 20.2  1  0    3    1
#7     Duster         360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.57 15.8  0  0    3    4
#8       Merc        240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.19 20.0  1  0    4    2
#9       <NA>         230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.15 22.9  1  0    4    2
#10      <NA>         280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.44 18.3  1  0    4    4
#11      <NA>        280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.44 18.9  1  0    4    4
#...
#...
```

which can be done in base R as

```
mycars[cols] <- lapply(my_cars[cols], function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA))
```